# Why does NotesDocument.send() insert "!\n " into HTML MIME body?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I'm using NotesDocument.send() to send HTML mails. With server-side javascript, the HTML code (html) is added to the NotesDocument (doc) as follows:

```
session.setConvertMime(false);
...
var mimeBody:NotesMIMEEntity=doc.createMIMEEntity("Body");
var stream:NotesStream=session.createStream();
stream.writeText(html);
mimeBody.setContentFromText(stream,"text/html;charset=\"UTF-8\"",NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
```

Sending the document works, but if the length of the HTML content exceeds a certain size, the resulting mail contains the string "!\n " at multiple positions. I thought there might be a problem with the MIME conversion and added "MailConvertMimeOnTransfer=0" to the notes.ini. Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

PS: I also tried using Mark Leusink's HTMLMail class from OpenNTF (http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime), but I also faced the problem described above.

**UPDATE**:
The problem only occurs with mails sent to internet users. Notes users recieve the correct HTML mail.

Comment: Try using Tony McGuckins email bean: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter

Comment: Can you be more specific about "certain size"? Is is ~40k?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: Thanks for the hint. I tried the email bean you suggested but the problem is the same there.

Comment: @stwissel: I guess you are mentioning the 40k due to this issue: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21220303 . However, "!\n " is inserted every ~1000 characters, i.e the problem already occurs for mails with a size of ~1kb.

Comment: when you say \n, you mean a slash and an n or do you mean a newline character? With no encoding your stream should have newlines plenty. Might be a mime issue

Comment: Yes, with \n I mean the newline character. The strange thing is that the HTML code is correct (=without "!\n ") inside the MIMEEntity. I checked this by saving the document after send. However, the HTML code of the mail I recieve is full of these "!\n " strings. Hence, NotesDocument.send() must somehow modify/convert the MIME body.

Comment: Did you try with encoding? MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT or MIMEEntity.ENC_BASE64

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I replaced NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_NONE with NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT and now it's working fine. After struggling with this problem for a few weeks now, I thank you very very much for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by altering the encoding of the MIME entity. I just changed the encoding from NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_NONE to **NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT**, and now the "!\n " strings a no longer inserted into to mail body when executing NotesDocument.send().

*All the credit is due to stwissel who provided this solution.*